# WebStorm become extremely slow when add unversioned js build file

Tags: javascript, git, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

##### I'm using webpack to generate js build file with a hash in its name.

When I run `yarn build` and click the commit panel in my WebStorm, it becomes extremely slow **when I check the Unversioned Files** as the picture show. WebStorm will be unresponsive for about 10 to 15 seconds.

It won't happen if I use git command in the command line.

My laptop is a MacbookPro 2019.

Can anybody tell me how to do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has been fixed after updating WebStorm to 2021.2.1